# VS 2012 Automatically updating IIS path on launch

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

My employer recently upgraded us from VS 2010 to VS 2012.  It's been great, but there is one minor annoyance that I'm hoping someone here can help with. In VS 2010 when I switched branches it would ask me whether I wanted to update the IIS paths. Something along the lines of "the path for port:blah is pointing here. Would you like to change it?" VS 2012 doesn't bother asking. It just changes it.  I can't seem to find a setting that discourages this behavior, so I'm hoping someone else out there has. Searching IIS on any site brings up way too many results to sift through, especially considering that only one (a topic from this forum, actually) of the first thirty or so had anything to do with IIS and Visual Studio updating the paths (sadly not related to this issue).  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I found the exact message. It reads: "The Web project '...' is currently configured to use the URL '...'. The Web server has this URL mapped to a different folder '...'. Would you like to remap this URL to point to this Web project's folder?"

Comment: Has no one else run into this issue? I'm still trying to find an answer, but no luck. If anyone else finds it, please post it here.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue.  The answer submitted doesn't look like much of an answer.  Has there been any additional solution for this?

Comment: Sadly, no. Their response is basically "This cannot be done.". It's annoying, but there you have it.

Comment: This is definitely an annoyance with VS 2012. Has anyone found a solution or workaround?

Comment: Yes, this is a really annoying issue that's been bugging me as well. For myself, one of my branches doesn't need to be mapped to an IIS application at all. I simply want to make sure it will compile before checking in. It's very tedious having to either manually update the physical path in IIS or restart VS. I didn't find this question at first, and was about to ask this same question until I found this.

Comment: @Itison: if for compile check, you can just use this cmd:

`msbuild <your project or solution> /P:Config=Debug`

It'll be faster than open it in VS 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this question to the MSDN forums. I received an answer there so I am just linking this question to the MSDN question.

[MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/b2ca64c1-afb1-4731-8e9c-fc68b3e4bd40/#9dd4639d-7dba-4eb8-8590-66e682f1c0f0)

[Request on visualstudio.uservoice.com](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3767262-give-us-a-setting-that-allows-us-to-automatically-)

Answer (score 1):

Just my work around for this problem:

- In IIS Manager, I created Sites for each branch, then I configured them using different Ports.
- Open each of the web projects in VS2012, then set the properties as:

  - `Start Action` = Don't open a page. Wait for request from external application.
  - `Servers` = Local IIS
  - `Project URL`: http://localhost:[PORT for this site on IIS]

This way, VS2012 will not modify the web port & path. I can still debug with different branches.

Is that helping you ?